# boost serialize and std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost

I Have a object which the following field :

```
boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Foo> > m_liste_;
```

I would like to serialize it, but it seems std::shared_ptr can't be serialized in a simple manner

anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Did you mean to write `boost::shared_ptr` rather than `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: yes initally  I would like to use std::shared_ptr, but with boost::shared_ptr and correct #include all is fine so I will stay with boost,thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect you are missing an include,

```
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

[link, at the bottom](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#examples)

Also, the example makes it look like aliasing and cycles are taken care of by default.

_Of course, having cycles will lead to potential memory leaks with shared_ptr that have nothing to do with serialization, and you'll still have to heed those (by avoiding cycles or judicious use of weak_ptr)_

See also:

- [Template serialization - shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/shared_ptr.html)
- [shared_ptrRevisited](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/shared_ptr2.html)

Answer (score -5):

Unfortunately the answer is that there isn't a simple way to serialise anything with pointers in it, because the memory layout of your data is likely to be different when you load it back in. A serialiser capable of dealing with pointers would need to be very smart, and come up with a 'memory layout' to save to disc that had valid pointer addresses in it for the stored structure, and which then rewrote them as the structure was deserialised in order to get the pointers pointing to the right places after loading is complete.

The really fun part is that if you allow pointers in serialisable structures you have to be able to cope with cyclic reference graphs. Also, `shared_ptr` keeps internal reference counts and accounting information so that it knows when to destroy an object, so the serialiser would need to know all about how that works as well, in order to correctly record reference counts (and ignore references from `shared_ptr` objects which aren't inside the serialised tree but do point to thinks inside it).

Basically it's a giant headache, and that's why serialisation libraries don't do it by default. You usually end up needing quite specific custom behaviour if you want to do it, so they leave it up to you to implement that in order to ensure it's done correctly.

Comment: Now, are you suggesting that Boost Serialization can't cope with the complexities you mention? I'm quite sure that it can. See the tutorial demo: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp

Comment: Nothing in that example serialises anything with pointers in it save for STL containers (which of course use them internall), which it explicitly notes already have specific support in the serialisation library. However, that example does show how to provide serialisation behaviour for your own types, which is the hook you use to serialise anything the library can't handle with its default knowledge.

Comment: `std::list<std::pair<trip_info, bus_route *> > schedule;` and `typedef bus_stop * bus_stop_pointer; std::list<bus_stop_pointer> stops;` - and **yes** bus stops are shared between routes. I wonder what link _you_ clicked?

Comment: Oh and that 'knowledge of implementing your classes' is (a) `ar & stops;` for bus_route and (b) `ar & schedule` for bus_schedule. The only added 'magic' is registering the polymorphic types for deserialization.