# Is there a library for creating fixed length primitive types?

Tags: c++

I am currently writing code in vs2012 which I want to compile in Linux. I want to serialise and save progress to a file and want that save file to be accessible on a 32-bit and 64-bit architecture, and both Windows and Linux.

I do not want to use any serialization libraries.

To achieve this I want to have functions which can convert and retrieve types, namely float, double, int32 and int64 (signed and unsigned) to fixed length and portable primitives for storage and retrieval in a binary file. My understanding is that bool and char types are specified in the standard and therefore already portable.

Performance is not critical but size is, so ASCII is not a viable solution here. I do not mind losing some precision if, for example, a platform uses a bit length larger than the fixed length I have specified, or vice versa.

As I am a newb too much talk of endianness, IEEE, etc. will confuse and irritate me.

I am particularly interested in a library that will do these conversions for me out of the box, but will consider rolling my own if that is the only way of achieving this.

FYI I don't want serialization libraries because boost doesn't work with smart pointers, cereal doesn't work with VS2012, and that Microsoft one doesn't work in Linux. If I'm going to have to doodle around to get these things to work I figure I might as well just do it myself.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** as I have now been schooled on the c++11 compatibility of the boost serialization library I will gladly settle for that solution.

Comment: _"I do not want to use any serialization libraries."_ and _"I am particularly interested in a library that will do these conversions for me out of the box, ..."_ seem to contradict eachother.

Comment: google protocol buffers?

Comment: @nightcracker I don't want to use a serialization library and I want the solution to convert types for me out of the box, as explained. I don't see the contradiction.

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot that's one solution but I don't like the idea of having to run a third party compiler to generate my headers every time I want to change something.

Comment: @ausairman Conversion from platform-specific data to a portable format and vice versa __is__ serialization.

Comment: @nightcracker Yes but I am only interested in converting primitives, and don't want to use a serialization library for the above reasons. If boost or others shipped with an option for converting primitives individually to bit strings and storing / retrieving those, then that would be an acceptable solution.

Comment: `As I am a newb too much talk of endianness, IEEE, etc. will confuse and irritate me.` Well, okay then. I won't confuse and irritate you with an answer. Good luck

Comment: @sehe Thanks I'll need it! I know this question is a long shot but it hasn't been framed like this on SO so I thought I'd give it a try. I think a lot of people would benefit from an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ausairman Boost Serialization very much ***does*** work with smart pointers:

- [boost serialize and std::shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944274/boost-serialize-and-stdshared-ptr/9944617#9944617)

```
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

The samples (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#examples) show this. Also, the example makes it look like aliasing and cycles are taken care of by default.

Since you mention straightup that endianness and other portability concerns confuse you, I very heartily suggest you do not write this yourself (unless it is purely with the goal of learning).

Comment: Cool, my understanding was that boost only worked with tr1::shared_ptr...

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in something that is not platform dependent and will store your values in memory with the same format that you wish to serialize, consider Cap'n Proto, which is written by the same author as Google's Protobuffers 2.0.

I am not sure whether smart pointers are used, and you might have to rewrite your objects to be backed by the Cap'n proto structs instead of primitive values, but this seems closest to what you want.

http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/

Comment: +1 for a protobuf derivative (?) that I didn't previously know

Comment: Thanks. I haven't had a change to try it yet, but I enjoyed working with Protocol Buffers, so I have bookmarked it for a project where it makes sense.

Comment: Very cool, will take a look

Comment: Unfortunately Cap'n Proto won't work with Visual Studio at present because VS's C++11 support is way behind Clang's and GCC's.  I have it on the roadmap to do a C++03 backport if VS doesn't catch up soon (which it looks like they won't).  Clang recently announced that they have experimental Visual C++ ABI compatibility so that might also be an option soon.

Comment: As an update to this, see https://github.com/bboreham/capnproto - I got quite a lot of Cap'n Proto to compile with the June 14 CTP of Visual Studio (alpha-test software) on Windows